# Andengine onAreaTouch with fast moves stops moving and dont make action up

Tags: performance, touch, andengine

Hi I'm making a small game and got this issue, the events runs well when I make a normal or slow moves but when I make very fast moves, the event crashes. Please what can I do?
This is my onAreaTouch event of my Sprite:

```
@Override
public boolean onAreaTouched(final TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, final float pTouchAreaLocalX, final float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
    int posInicial=estadoCarta;
        switch(pSceneTouchEvent.getAction()) {
             case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                 posX=getX()-getWidth()/2;
                 posY=getY()-getHeight()/2;
                 this.setScale(1.2f);
                 break;
             case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                 switch(estadoCarta){
                    case POS_PJ1:
                        this.setPosition(pSceneTouchEvent.getX() - this.getWidth() / 2, pSceneTouchEvent.getY() - this.getHeight() / 2);
                        if(pSceneTouchEvent.getY()<=430){
                             this.setAlpha((float) 0.5);
                             estadoCarta=POS_SELECIONADO_MESA;
                        }
                    break;
                    case POS_SELECIONADO_MESA:
                        this.setPosition(pSceneTouchEvent.getX() - this.getWidth() / 2, pSceneTouchEvent.getY() - this.getHeight() / 2);
                        if(pSceneTouchEvent.getY()>430){
                             this.setAlpha((float) 1);
                             estadoCarta=POS_PJ1;
                        }
                    break;
                 }
                 break;


            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                this.setScale(1.0f);

                switch(estadoCarta){
                    case POS_PJ1:
                        setPosition(posX+getWidth()/2,posY+getHeight()/2);
                        estadoCarta=posInicial;
                    break;
                    case POS_SELECIONADO_MESA:
                        Posicion pos=escena.getPosicionLibre();
                        this.setPosition(pos.x,  pos.y);
                        escena.Juega(this);
                    break;
                 }
                 break;
            default:
                this.setScale(1.0f);
                switch(estadoCarta){
                    case POS_PJ1:
                        setPosition(posX+getWidth()/2,posY+getHeight()/2);
                        estadoCarta=posInicial;
                    break;
                    case POS_SELECIONADO_MESA:
                        Posicion pos=escena.getPosicionLibre();
                        this.setPosition(pos.x,  pos.y);
                        escena.Juega(this);
                    break;
                    case POS_MESA:
                        this.setAlpha(0.5f);
                        estadoCarta=POS_PARA_JUGAR;
                    break;
                    case POS_PARA_JUGAR:
                         this.setAlpha(1f);
                         estadoCarta=POS_MESA;
                    break;
                 }
                break;
         }
    return true;
}
```

I repeat the issue is only when I make a fast move.

Comment: what error message do you get?

Comment: I dont get any error. But when I move fast the finger, the sprite stop moving and dont make any action after. I want to get that move and put any action and dont stop the touch area event with any event

Comment: Does the entire app become unresponsive? Or just that one sprite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isolved it!!!
I use this code in EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() of may main game activity:

```
public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions()
{
    camera = new BoundCamera(0, 0, 800, 480);
    EngineOptions engineOptions = new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED, new FillResolutionPolicy(), this.camera);
    engineOptions.getAudioOptions().setNeedsMusic(true).setNeedsSound(true);
    engineOptions.setWakeLockOptions(WakeLockOptions.SCREEN_ON);
    engineOptions.getTouchOptions().setTouchEventIntervalMilliseconds(1);
    return engineOptions;
}
```

This help me to reduce the normal 20 miliseconds transition to 1. Then the touch efects responds faster!!

Comment: setTouchEventIntervalMilliseconds(1) this method present GLES 1 or GLES 2 ? currently i am using AndEngine library  but above method is not present  int it . so Any suggestion for same qustion ?